# What can be done about problematic suggested edits?

Tags: support, review, flagging, suggested-edits

When one encounters a problematic suggested edit one has the option to reject it. 
However, in some cases it might seem like more should be done 
(this includes a persistent pattern of problematic edits or highly inappropriate edits, 
such as vandalism).

How can one draw the moderators attention to problematic suggested edits?

Can one flag problematic suggested edits?

Is this something that should be done?

Comment: Note that while I don't think it's controversial, this is not (yet) a collective/official post of the mod team.

Answer (score 8):

**How can one draw the moderators attention to problematic suggested edits?  Can one flag problematic suggested edits?**

The interface in the review queue for suggested edits does not directly offer any option to contact the moderators. It is not directly possible to flag the suggestion.

However, one can flag the post instead. If one sees the edit on the post, this is easy. If one is in the review queue one can note that the title of the post is a link to the post.

Thus, one can open the post, in a new tab for example, and flag the post as in need for moderator intervention with a description of the problem.

To avoid confusions one should start out by saying that the problem is with a suggested edit and then proceed to describe the nature of the problem. Moderators can locate the suggested edit, it is not necessary to link to the review task in the flag (if it is done it is also fine).
Please make sure to flag the actual post though, not just any post in the same Q&A pair,

**Is this something that should be done?**

In general, it suffices to reject a poor suggested edit. However, if you observe a larger number of problematic edits from the same source or suggested edits that seem to be made in bad faith (defacing the post, trying to add vulgarity, etc) it is useful to signal this to the moderators.

It is not unlike with poor posts. Not every poor question should be flagged for our attention, but if there is a bigger problem, then we do want to know about it. Depending on the nature of the problem we then can decide how to proceed.

Comment: If you would like a feature that allows to flag more directly from the queue, please upvote this comment.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning automatic suggested edit bans: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel  Thanks!  While a seven-day ban is likely sufficient in most cases, in some cases, such a ban that does not automatically escalate to greater-length-of-time bans upon further abuse, isn't necessarily sufficient.  But do you have any links to meta.se posts about abuse by "anonymous users'" suggested edits, who are not required to register?  I run into a lot of efforts from "anonymous user" to vandalize posts in their suggested edits.  I reject, or reject and edit, but does the system also ban such users after too many rejected edits?

Comment: I suspect that, as unregistered users, the system cannot detect them to ban them.  Any suggestions as to how to deal with such edits?

Comment: @amWhy there's an [IP block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118213/295232)

Comment: Thanks for the added info, @Glorfindel!

Comment: @Glorfindel good idea and thanks for the links. I'll update later.